# Ritualized wrestling for lizardfolk?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, martial-arts

Asian water monitors. They're cute and intelligent, so I decided to base lizardfolk off of them. Nothing new there. Now, I also want to implement one interesting aspect of water monitors into them: wrestling.

If you don't know what I'm talking about, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0tOdjvZXSM) with the sound off unless you want to get a stroke.

Now, lizardfolk are large (around the size of a human, but slightly taller on average), more human-like in posture and body plan/proportions. They're also mesotherms, meaning they can produce heat, but still don't have the same degree of control over their body temperature as humans.

**The question is what would ritualized wrestling look like for them? Namely, how water would be integrated into the equation (moves and safety precautions), as lizardfolk can hold their breath pretty well.**

In paper, wrestling among lizardfolk is done as recreation, competition and rarely as trial by combat (when there isn't enough evidence). So, it's (again, in paper) **a safe and regulated way to handle conflicts when they escalate**.

Comment: Will they have to wrestle fully submerged at any time or will the water only be to a certain height on their body?

Comment: @RandySavage Real monitors don't really use their legs to sweep. Their dominance displays are mostly face to face pushing matches.

Comment: @RandySavage They won't be fully submerged when standing, it depends on where the arena is (usually a swamp).

Comment: @user2352714 I deleted that comment but I asked because if they were humanoid they would try and sweep which the lizards cant, but sweeping in water is pointless or you need to adjust strength,

Comment: water and wrestling is a bad mix unless they are really really good at holding their breath against impacts and squeezing which is all but impossible. Also if they are human sized mesotherms getting in water will drop their body temperature like a stone and they will likely avoid it at all costs.  you would be better off with mud wrestling, less heat loss less issues,

Comment: I watched the video with the sound on... It didn't give me a stroke, but I think it did give me cancer. However, I did have to VTC as too story-based. The rules of human wrestling (the word "ritualized" doesn't mean anything) developed over centuries of experience based on the goals of the sport and the consequences to the players. The key word here is "experience." AKA, your story.

Comment: i think somebody need to give them some pointers, it doesn't look like tango... stepping on foot is beginner cold water won't help the pain ;D

Comment: do they need to be in water or fully submerge ? because monitor lizard wrestling can be anywhere most of the time on dry land, and as far as i know, i never see monitor lizard wrestling while fully submerge, even in that video the water is shallow enough for them to stand up, also just a little trivia, [komodo dragon](https://i.redd.it/65h821971bu11.jpg) also do this.

Comment: also maybe try check mud wrestling, for moves and safety precaution, since the floor probably slippery or to soft for proper footing like in wet mud.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking about the rules of engagement, right !!

If that's so then the official rules of LizardFolk Wrestling league are:

- All matches are to be conducted in muddy-swamp water 4 feet deep.
  Each match will be of 3 rounds, with 2 minutes each.
- The decision will be based on either points or KnockOuts.
- KnockOuts will be of 3 types:

  1. The usual KnockOut.
  2. If a player can submerge the opponent into water (tail included) for 10 seconds, the opponent is considered knocked-out.
  3. If a player throws the opponent from his tail completely out of the water, the opponent is considered knocked-out.
- In the case of KnockOuts, the match is terminated immediately.
- Points will be as:

  1. Submerging the opponent's head into the water is 1 point.
  2. The biting of the opponent's tail is 2 points.
  3. Hitting opponent's head with tail is 5 points.
- Player Elimination:
  Biting anywhere other than opponent tail results in elimination.
  Intentional use of nails is elimination.
  and some other unethical means.

Apart from these, we also have bonus tie-breaker rounds like capture the flag and find the sunken pearl.